# Import of font-awesome via angular-cli.json in angular 6 version?

Tags: angular, sass, angular5, font-awesome

I was assigned by instructor to import font-awesome in angular-cli.json file but i am using angular 6 so i initialize font awesome node module in angular.json file but it is not working and error in ng serve.

Comment: There's not much we can do to help unless you let us know what the error is, and probably post your `angular.json` file as well

Comment: what's the command you used to install font-awesome ?

Answer (score 3):

Install Packages `npm install --save font-awesome angular-font-awesome`

Import the module:

```
//...
import { AngularFontAwesomeModule } from 'angular-font-awesome';
@NgModule({
  //...
  imports: [
    //...
    AngularFontAwesomeModule
  ],
  //...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

If you're using Angular CLI, add the font-awesome CSS to `styles` inside the `angular-cli.json`

```
"styles": [
    "styles.css",
    "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css"
],
```

NOTE: If using SCSS preprocessor just change the css for scss

If you're not using the CLI, import the stylesheet to your index.html file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
```

If you used the wrong command to install font-awesome:

1. remove the dependency installed from `package.json`
2. remove `node_modules` folder manually.
3. run `npm cache clean --force`
4. run `npm install`
5. and do the steps I've mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

From https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome:

```
npm install –save '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome' 

npm install –save ‘@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core' 

npm i --save '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
```

Keeping in mind the guide did not mention having to run the last two commands, but they are dependencies required by Font Awesome.